# Persistent storage not working

Tags: persistence

i made a Ubuntu live usb stick using Lili software. After that i made a partition using Gparted on kali of 3.5GB for persistent storage and renamed it casper-rw. But everytime i reboot the files i save are lost. I mean it boots from start everytime and all old changes are lost.
I want Ubuntu on my 8 GB usb that can save files which are not lost on rebooting. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i faced something similar recently. 
So, i used gparted to format for USB with FAT32. 
Secondly, i used mkusd in order to build up the persistent installation of Xubuntu 17.
I tried other options and tools for persistent storage, but the combination was the one that worked fine.
Regards,
CJ

Comment: You may want to improve your answer by adding a link where to find information about mkusb, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb